# temporarily replace content of has_many relationship

Tags: activerecord

when my model is in a particular state, I need to render it with hiding some specific data.

my model knows the data I need to hide through a `has_many` relationship.

my idea is to retrieve the model, replace the content of the `has_many` relationship with a dummy, non persisted object, and then render it, without saving the model.
So that when rendering the data shown will be from the dummy object.

here's my code:

the model:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
   .... 
   has_many :owners
   ....
end
```

in the controller:

```
@car.owners = [ Owner.new(name: "", phone: "") ] if hide_owner?
```

it actually attempts to do the update on the DB and fails with this error:

```
*** ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved Exception: Failed to replace owners because one or more of the new records could not be saved.
```

Answer (score 0):

It feels like this would be easier if you were accessing a Decorator class instead of the model directly.

Then in the decorator you could define:

```
def owners
  if hide_owner?
    [ Owner.new(name: "", phone: "") ]
  else
    object.owners
  end
end
```

... where `object` is the instance of Car.

Maybe look at the Draper gem or others.